# Show that $R_{\mu\nu}=C g_{\mu\nu}$ from the vacuum Einstein equation with a nonzero $\Lambda$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature, tensor-calculus

If I begin with the vacuum field equation with a nonzero cosmological constant:

$$R_{\mu\nu}-\dfrac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R+g_{\mu\nu}\Lambda=0$$

How can I show that

$$R_{\mu\nu}= \frac{\Lambda}{\frac{D}{2}-1}g_{\mu\nu}$$

Where D is the number of dimensions.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What's there to show? Obviously this implies $R_{\mu\nu}=(1/2 R-\Lambda)g_{\mu\nu}$ and both $R$ and $\Lambda$ are constants...

Comment: Multiply by $g^{\mu\nu}$

Comment: Yes, so i get $R_{\mu\nu}=(\frac{R}{2}-\Lambda)g_{\mu\nu}$. If I multiply both sides by $g^{\mu\nu}$ I get $R=(\frac{R}{2}-\Lambda)D$.But rearranging this doesn't give me the equation I'm supposed to prove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a trace of Einstein equations (trace of $g_{\mu \nu}$ is $D$), you obtain
$$R - \frac{D}{2} R + D \Lambda = 0$$
Or $$R=\frac{D \Lambda}{D/2-1}$$ Then substitute this expression for $R$ into full Einstein equations and you obtain trivially
$$R_{\mu \nu } = \frac{\Lambda}{D/2 - 1} g_{\mu \nu}$$

Comment: The sign was absorbed by a change of sign of the denominator, you can verify this directly.